# scrapy startproject doesn't use designated TEMPLATES_DIR for generating project settings.py

Tags: python, templates, scrapy, settings

When I run scrapy (0.24.6) like this:

`scrapy startproject -s TEMPLATES_DIR=local_templates_dir my_project`

I get a `my_project/my_project/settings.py` that is clearly generated from the package default `scrapy/templates/project/module/settings.py.tmpl`, not from the template found under my `local_templates_dir`, which by the way, has the same directory structure as found in `scrapy/templates`. There are no error or warning messages.

Although the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html) seems to suggest this is the thing to do, the code in `scrapy/commands/startproject.py` seems to say I can't expect this to work at all. It appears to be hardcoded for the package templates folder. Am I missing something, an environment setting perhaps that would make this work the way I expect? Do I need to write a [custom command module](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#custom-project-commands) just to get the correct settings?

The motivation is simply to have a local project settings template for my team, not a default one requiring that each developer has to update the `settings.py` manually after running startproject.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry I only just now found this on github: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/671 reporting the problem I have, and a future fix: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1035

Answer (score 2):

Yeap, you're right, that's currently a limitation of Scrapy templating.

So, in your shoes, I'd just use a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) template instead.

Scrapy templates are nice for someone getting started into Scrapy, but  Cookiecutter has several advantages over it: you can add custom variables to be asked when creating a project, you can use variables in directory names, call cookiecutter from a Python script, etc. All these pay dividends when maintaining your own template project.

Also, you can reuse the knowledge of cookiecutter for any other project (even non-Python related), so it seems a real nice investment. :)

Comment: I suggest using github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django. ;)